# How to solve this error message from Eclipse: The path '$/... ' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path for TFS

Tags: eclipse

I just installed the TFS plug in and conneccted to the TFS server.

First, it says

> The source control folder tree could not be refreshed.

Later, I was trying to check in, Eclipse complained about

> The path '$/...' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component.
>   Remove the '$' and try again.

But I just connected to the tfs using Team-> Share Project and the popup window showed me $/.... in the server path in Confirmation page before I click Finish.  So why was this plug-in add a $ in the server path and then complain about it?

I am using TFS2012, and the plug-in is 12.0.1.20140304643